# how to share variable between python and go language?

Tags: python, variables, environment-variables, go, share

i need to know how share variable between two program,
basically the go program have to write a variable ,like a string, and the python program have to read this variable.
Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some context to your question? Maybe some code would help… Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use standard streams. use a simple `printf` type command to print the string to stdout.  then read it with a `raw_input()` in python.

run the two programs like so:

`./output | ./read.py`

Comment: i can not use standard streams, i need a solution without ones

Comment: You can print your variable to tmp file and then read it from python code.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, most common way to do communication between two processes is "Named Pipe" (could also be tcp/ip, web service, etc...).

A ugly but lighter way is to write the value to a file, and read it from python.